# String Justification using C

Tags: c

So I have to write to a file the strings as well as the length of that string. The output should look like this:

```
======= =====
merrily   7
    row   3
   your   4
   boat   4
 gently   6
   down   4
    the   3
  dream   5
 stream   6
   life   4
     is   2
    but   3
      a   1
```

So I have a string array called `char big[50]` that holds the string of the biggest length within the list. If I use `strlen(big)` I would then get 7 because `merrily` is the biggest string in that list and have a word count of 7. So how am I supposed to print it with justification? I cant write `fprintf(fpOut, "%7s   %d\n, table[i], strlen(table[i]);` because my program has multiple files that the user can open and if I use `%7s` it wouldn't justify correctly for other files. Is there a solution around this?

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the constant width specifier (7) with an asterisk to obtain a variable width specifier. So the following code would have a width specifier of `strlen(big)`:

```
fprintf(fpOut, "%*s %d\n", strlen(big), table[i], strlen(table[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you that you could do that. I really appreciate the insight.

Comment: No problem, it's a pretty neat (and useful) feature!

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  printf("%*s |\n", 7, "let"); 
  // or to file:  fprintf(file, "%*s |\n", 7, "let");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the length of the string in fprintf arguments. You can also take a look at my project: libtprint - a simple library to print tabled data, https://github.com/wizzard/libtprint . There I use various tricks to justify strings.

Hope it helps !